# Eroneous migration file from Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Something weird just happened to me with Symfony. 
I'm adding a Picture entity with a ManyToOne relation to an existing Article entity. The wizard gave me those modified entities:

```
#App/Entity/Picture.php


 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PictureRepository")
 */
class Picture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adress;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\article", inversedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $article;
```

and

```
#App/Entity/Article.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $Text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", mappedBy="Article")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Picture", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $pictures;
```

Those seems good to me, but when making the migration, the "article_id" field in the picture table is not created. Here is the migration code generated:

```
 $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE picture (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, adress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

Obviously, no relation is stored, and I can't use this relation in my code.

Am I missing something?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to delete the new migration and re-create it again, if the same migration was generated try to validate the schema  using "php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate" command , maybe there's a typo in the file

Comment: Thanks for this help. Unfortunatly, it didn't work, as the Symfony cache kept the typo until it was cleared. Found this when trying to rename the $adress property, and caught a `Property App\Entity\Picture::$adress does not exist` error. This made me look where this property can be kept.

Comment: Glad that you found the problem, it's also recommended that you develop in the dev mode ( changing the APP_ENV to "dev" in your .env.local ) which doesn't cache the files by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alleluiah! Found this one.

It seems I made a typo at a moment, and the Symfony cache kept it even when corrected.

Just had to:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Then to make a new migration, everything went fine.